# Is there any way to include all the outside .jar into maven repository without using the install:install file command

Tags: maven, repository, m2e

In my project, a lot of .jar files are used and they are not in the maven repository(both local and web).

Exception using install command to include them in the repository one by one, is there any approach or plugin to put them in the repository for one time.

And if there is, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I am not aware of any way you can get around that. You could write a script that will add all the jar files to the local repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kal says in the comments, use a script. This is what we use - just modify the values in each of the `set` statements

```
set GROUP_ID=someNamespace
set ARTIFACT_ID=myartifact
set VERSION=1
set COMPONENT=%ARTIFACT_ID%-%VERSION%
set FILEPATH=D:\my.jar

call mvn install:install-file ^
 -DgroupId=%GROUP_ID% ^
 -DartifactId=%ARTIFACT_ID% ^
 -Dversion=%VERSION% ^
 -Dfile=%FILEPATH% ^
 -Dpackaging=jar ^
 -DgeneratePom=true

set GROUP_ID=someNamespace2
set ARTIFACT_ID=myartifact2
set VERSION=1
set COMPONENT=%ARTIFACT_ID%-%VERSION%
set FILEPATH=D:\my2.jar

call mvn install:install-file ^
 -DgroupId=%GROUP_ID% ^
 -DartifactId=%ARTIFACT_ID% ^
 -Dversion=%VERSION% ^
 -Dfile=%FILEPATH% ^
 -Dpackaging=jar ^
 -DgeneratePom=true
```